# Public datasets to 'practice' on

Tags: dataset

I recently received an assignment in my Java programming class to analyze a (what I would guess is a very small) dataset. I really enjoyed the assignment and the use of a 'tokenizer' etc which was a new concept to me. The dataset we got to work with was pretty boring, as it only contained dates.

**What I'm looking for is:**
Public datasets (XML, txt or similar) to practice analysis on

This can be anything really (preferably pretty simply), as I'm mainly trying to print out statistics, patterns and graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Stackoverflow [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

Answer (score 3):

The [UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) is a great resource for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the raw data dump mentioned by [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100201/public-datasets-to-practice-on/4100243#4100243), see its companion, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).  There, you can run a SQL query and download the resultset.  (Useful if you're looking for something smaller than *everything*.)